# Unable to save channels to PFInstallation (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to add / remove channels from PFInstallation but I keep getting the same error message:

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Operation is invalid after previous operation.'
```

My code:

```
NSString * channel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", city, @"_", self.titleLabel.text];
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
if([sender isOn]){
    [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:channel forKey:@"channels"];
} else{
    [currentInstallation removeObject:channel forKey:@"channels"];
}
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in addUniqueObject method, when channels is nil.
You should add this before it.

```
if (currentInstallation.channels == nil)
{
    currentInstallation.channels = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}
```

Also, you should use saveEventually instead of saveInBackGround.

This should be a bug in SDK.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me! :)