# addUniqueObject property causes compiler error in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My code:

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
//Parse Remote Push Notification setup
let userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
    UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
    UIUserNotificationType.Sound);

let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

The function setting up the initial channel:

```
//Parse push remote necessary functions 
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
installation.addUniqueObject("riders" forKey: "channels")
installation.save()
}
```

I get an error message on this line:

```
installation.addUniqueObject("riders" forKey: "channels")
```

Error: expected separator

I saw another stack question that said I should check for nil first :

[Unable to save channels to PFInstallation (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672290/unable-to-save-channels-to-pfinstallation-ios)

But:

(1) the answer is in objective-C and I do not know how to translate this into Swift:

```
if (currentInstallation.channels == nil)
{
    currentInstallation.channels = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}
```

(2) I'm wondering if this is the only thing I need to do or if this is the best solution for this problem?  Apparently it is a known Parse SDK bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You are doing everything right, you just have a typo. As the error shows already says that it expects a separator. Often this error is misleading, but in your case, it leads straight to your problem: Just add a `,` between your parameters:

From:

```
installation.addUniqueObject("riders" forKey: "channels")
```

To:

```
installation.addUniqueObject("riders", forKey: "channels")
```

Comment: That's the first time I've seen that error that it's actually turned out to be the case.  It's always been something else.   Parse's tutorial (https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS) does not include the comma so I assumed there was more to it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add a channel:

```
currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("channel-name", forKey:"channels")
currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

To remove a channel:

```
currentInstallation.removeObject("channel-name", forKey:"channels")
currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

To get current channels:

```
if let channels: [String] = currentInstallation.channels as? [String] {
  // Process list of channels. 
}
```

And of course, to get the current installation:

```
let currentInstallation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
```

See example use below:

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class DWWatchlistController {

  private let currentInstallation: PFInstallation
  private let stocks:[SNStock]
  private(set) var watchlist:[SNStock]

  init(stocks:[SNStock]) {
    self.stocks = stocks
    self.currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    self.watchlist = []
    updateWatchlist()
  }

  func addStock(stock: SNStock) {
    currentInstallation.addUniqueObject(stock.ticker, forKey:"channels")
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    updateWatchlist()
  }

  func removeStock(stock: SNStock) {
    currentInstallation.removeObject(stock.ticker, forKey:"channels")
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    updateWatchlist()
  }

  private func updateWatchlist() {
    watchlist = fetchSubscribedStocks()
  }

  private func fetchSubscribedStocks() -> [SNStock] {
    if let channels: [String] = currentInstallation.channels as? [String] {
      return stocks.filter({ (stock: SNStock) -> Bool in
        return contains(channels, stock.ticker as String)
      })
    }
    return []
  }
}
```