# Push notifications in iOS with Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to set an unique channel for each app user.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    NSString  *currentDeviceId = [[device identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
    NSLog(@"DEVICE=%@",currentDeviceId);
    NSMutableString *canal = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"a" ];
    [canal appendString:currentDeviceId];
    NSLog(@"CANAL=%@",canal);
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:canal forKey:@"channels"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

The log for the channel name is:

```
CANAL=a35EFF93B-6CD0-4D09-9AE2... (hidden here rest of id)
```

But I get the error:

```
[Error]: Channel name must start with a letter
```

As you can see, the channel name starts with a letter.
What am I doing wrong here?

EDITED

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    NSString  *currentDeviceId = [[device identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
    NSLog(@"DEVICE=%@",currentDeviceId);
    NSMutableString *canal = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"a" ];
    [canal appendString:currentDeviceId];
    NSLog(@"CANAL=%@",canal);

    if (currentInstallation.channels == nil)
    {
        currentInstallation.channels = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:canal forKey:@"channels"];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];

    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672290/unable-to-save-channels-to-pfinstallation-ios

Comment: remove `< >` symbol from deviceToken.work for you.

Comment: @picciano, thank you, changed but the same error...please take  a look at my updated question.

Comment: @SumitGarg, thank you, but I don't see there any <>.

Comment: deviceToken is an object of NSData, when you convert it into string it will return string in format `<device token>`.

Comment: @SumitGarg, thank you, but I don't have any issue regarding the device token, it is working fine, my problem is creating a channel.

Comment: error on this line `[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:canal forKey:@"channels"];`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];

with this

```
NSString *tokenString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[deviceToken bytes]];

NSString* neweviceToken = [[[[tokenString description]
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
```

and the run.

May help you.

Comment: Thank you, but your proposal has nothing to do with my question, or do you think it does?